# React Functional Component update property change

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-star package

`import ReactStars from "react-rating-stars-component";`

It has one issue.
I need to the value to change on state change. But the value is not changing

I am changing the this.state.rating on ajax load.
and setting the value this.rating to be used in submit.

```
class CallUpdate extends Component<{ match: PropsWithRef<any> }> {
 state = {
        rating:0
    }
    rating = 0;

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        this.id = this.props.match.params.id;



        const userCall = await axios.get(`call/show/${this.id}`);

        const call: call= userCall.data.data;
        this.setState({
            rating: call.rating
        });
    }

    submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('rating', this.rating);
        //const formHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
        const config = {headers: {'Content-Type' :'multipart/form-data'}};
        await axios.post(`call/${this.id}/update`, formData,config);

    }
render() {
return (
<ReactStars
    count={5}
    value={this.state.rating}
    onChange={(rating) => {this.rating = rating}}
    size={24}
    activeColor="#ffd700"
/>
        );
    }
}

export default CallUpdate;
////
react-starts-component  I have added this function. it should be called on props change.

 function updateValue(value){
        if (value < 0 || value > count) {
            setCurrentValue(0);
        }
        else {
            setCurrentValue(value);
        }
    }

I tried changing the useEffect 
useEffect(() => {
        addClassNames();
        validateInitialValue(props.value, props.count);
        setStars(getStars(props.value));
        setConfig(props);
        createUniqueness();
        setIsUsingIcons(iconsUsed(props));
        setHalfStarAt(Math.floor(props.value));
        setHalfStarHidden(props.isHalf && props.value % 1 < 0.5);
    }, []);

to 

useEffect(() => {
        addClassNames();
        validateInitialValue(props.value, props.count);
        setStars(getStars(props.value));
        setConfig(props);
        createUniqueness();
        setIsUsingIcons(iconsUsed(props));
        setHalfStarAt(Math.floor(props.value));
        setHalfStarHidden(props.isHalf && props.value % 1 < 0.5);
    }, [props]);
```

But on state.rating change it is not updating the value.

How do I change the code to make it property change value?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the rating to the value when the value changes?

Comment: yes I it is not change now.value property is not changing when state changes

Comment: This is an issue in open issue in the app.They have provided an alternative solution to use key property. that is not working on typescripts

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are not updating the state but instead updating a property on class which doesn't cause a re-render and you are using `lead` whereas you have a `call` variable in componentDidMount which doesn't exists. You should use a state variable to hold data that might change overtime and reflect in UI.

```
class CallUpdate extends Component {
  state = {
    rating: 0
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;

    const userCall = await axios.get(`call/show/${this.id}`);

    const call: call = userCall.data.data;
    this.setState({
      rating: call.rating
    });
  };

  submit = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("rating", this.rating);
    //const formHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
    await axios.post(`call/${this.id}/update`, formData, config);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactStars
        count={5}
        value={this.state.rating}
        onChange={(rating) => this.setState({rating})}
        size={24}
        activeColor="#ffd700"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not on change

Comment: I am changing the state via ajax load

Comment: Please check now

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your code, check.

Comment: sorry it typo call it should be not lead

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same problem when value not updating from useMemo().* You just need to add key prop to ReactStars: `key={value}`